# Create dynamic methods for classes in typescipt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In javascript I can create methods dinamically inside a class, like so:

```
const methods = ['error', 'info', 'warning', 'debug'];
class Logger {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'log';
        for (const method of methods) {
            this[method] = () => {
                console.log(method);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same but in TypeScript?

Comment: Typespript is just the syntactic sugar for JavaScript. So any javascript is valid in typescript

Comment: @Gorynych Syntactically valid yes (and for JSX there are even exceptions), but that doesn't mean it will typecheck.